# One activity, two screens, one ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imageview

I'm creating an Android application, but I don't know how to manage my UI.
I have a main fragment set inside the MainActivity, and at top right a button to open another Fragment.
However the two classes of fragments just define layouts and toolbar.
So I have a first quetion, Is that a good pratice to use Fragments or it's better to use 2 Activities ?

I also have an ImageView inside MainActivity and and displayed in the main fragment. I defined a Bitmap in onStart() method.
But after open the second fragment and go back to the main (with back button or with the <- button in toolbar), the ImageView displays the default bitmap setted in the XML. How to avoid losting the Bitmap I have setted ? How work fragments and backstack ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using 2 Activities instead of 2 Fragments is an easy workaround to guide your app into an architectural mess. Keep track of your selected image resource  as a field, persist it to Bundle in onSaveInstanceState, and restore in onCreate. Don't put Bitmap in Bundle tho.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my app is an app of picture retouching. That mean at each time the user will click on the "info button" of the picture , that will save the current edited picture in Cache to reload them from Uri when go back to the main fragment. I will may be just play with visibility of layout components :S

Comment: If you need a quick and easy solution that is not the standard but it is easier than the standard, then you might want to check https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack-tutorials/blob/19961bcc62a34f68e5b418ded294f37717ef4a41/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestacktutorials/steps/step_2/Step2Activity.kt#L24-L45